# Where can I change my Pokemon's nickname?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

In the previous generations, there was a Name Rater who could help you change your Pokemon's nickname, unless it was traded. Where is the Name Rater in this generation?

Comment: He's in a Pokécenter either in *Santalune City* or *Camphrier Town*. I forgot which and I can't fly back yet.

Comment: Unless it was traded?
That explains why I can't change my Farfetch'd's name. Guess I'm stuck with "Quacklin" :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Talk to the man in the Pokemon Centre at Camphrier Town. When you enter the building, he's on the right side.

He can change your Pokemon's nickname, the same as any other generation (I presume so, as you have described)

Comment: Oh, I missed that it doesn't work on traded pokemon.  Dang, guess I'm stuck with a team of Japanese pokemon.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft if it's unevolved it will turn into an English (or your current language) name after the evolution.